# display the display member of a combo box for a Given integer Value member

Tags: c#, combobox, windows-forms-designer

I have a `ComboBox` in my project which I have assigned a `DisplayMember` and a `ValueMember`. I want the `ComboBox` to display the relevant `DisplayMember` when a  `ValueMember` value is given to the `ComboBox`. 
Code examples will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: `cbxEmployeeDepartment.SelectedValue=_dataTable.Rows[0]`["DesignationId"].ToString(); `                                                                                          This code worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simple;

```
    comboBox1.SelectedValue = "2"; // it will show you respected display member
```